# How to insert multiple records from different textboxes in a single table?

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, linq

I have a view which consists of Eight `Textboxes` for taking input of Question's Options text from user to submit in `DataBase` Table.
The values will go into table called Question_Options with the same Question_Id(F.K) which i saved in a hidden field now i have to submit all `TextBoxes` values in `DataBase`, i want to do it through loop ....please any idea ....i am just a beginner.

My HTML code is

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Option 1
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HF_QidOpt" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_OptText" runat="server" Height="54px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="310px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>Option 1 Description</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_OptDesc" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="54px" Width="310px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Option 2</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_OptText2" runat="server" Height="54px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="310px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>Option 2 Description</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_OptDesc2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="54px" Width="310px"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Option 3</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_OptText3" runat="server" Height="54px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="310px"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td>Option 3 Description</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_OptDesc3" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="54px" Width="310px"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Option 4</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_OptText4" runat="server" Height="54px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="310px"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td>Option 4 Description</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_OptDesc4" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="54px" Width="310px"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn_Create_Option" runat="server" Text="Create Option" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

and i have tried this one but unable to get values

```
Try
            Dim DB As New SQLDBDataContext
            Dim NGUID As New System.Guid(HF_QidOpt.Value.ToString)
            Dim boxes As TextBox() = New TextBox() {txt_OptText, txt_OptText2, txt_OptText3, txt_OptText4, txt_OptDesc, txt_OptDesc2, txt_OptDesc3, txt_OptDesc4}
            For Each t As TextBox In boxes
                If t IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim CO As New Question_Option
                    With CO
                        .UID = System.Guid.NewGuid
                        .Question_ID = NGUID
                        .Option_Text = 'How to get value of txt_OptText, txt_OptText2, txt_OptText3, txt_OptText4'
                        .Option_Description = 'How to get value of txt_OptDesc, txt_OptDesc2, txt_OptDesc3, txt_OptDesc4'
                    End With
                    DB.Question_Options.InsertOnSubmit(CO)
                End If
            Next
                    DB.SubmitChanges()
                    MV_Default.SetActiveView(V_Success)

        Catch ex As Exception
            lbl_Failure.Text = ex.Message
            MV_Default.SetActiveView(V_Failure)
```

End Try

Answer (score 1):

You have to use UNION ALLs in SQL Server to insert multiple rows in a SQL script in a single statement.

```
   INSERT INTO Table 
     (Name, Location) 
  SELECT 'Name1', 'Location1' 
  UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Name2', 'Location2'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Name3', 'Location3'
```

ref [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/08/sql-server-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-union-all/) and [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1146530.aspx)